# Why is the result of $\int_0^1 (\ln (1/x))^{p-1}dx=\Gamma (p)$?

Tags: calculus, gamma-function

I solved this and found the answer to be $-Gamma (p)$. The book gives the answer as $Gamma (p)$. Which of us is right?

**My sol:**

Let $x=e^{-u}$, $dx = -e^{-u}du$, $\ln(1/x)=\ln(1)-\ln(x)$

$$\to \int u^{p-1}(-e^{-u})du$$
$$=-\Gamma (p)$$

Comment: You need to consider the integral limits. Your "$-$" is needed to get from $\int_\infty^0$ to $\int_0^\infty$.

Comment: Yea I had no clue what to do with the integral limits. I knew that with a u-substitution we generally need to adjust them, but in a previous problem I didn't have to and I got it right, so I was improperly conditioned :p

Comment: Wait, why do you speak of $\int_{\infty}^0$ in the first place?

Comment: Because $x = 0$ corresponds to $u = \infty$, and $x = 1$ to $u = 0$. $$\int_{x = 0}^{x = 1} \bigl(\ln (1/x)\bigr)^{p-1}\,dx = \int_{e^{-u} = 0}^{e^{-u} = 1} \bigl(\ln (1/e^{-u})\bigr)^{p-1}\,de^{-u} = - \int_{u = \infty}^{u = 0} u^{p-1}e^{-u}\,du.$$

Answer (score 1):

Because your limits of integration will be inverted.

Comment: Why do I need to invert them?

Comment: $u=-\ln x$. When $x=0$ you have $u=\infty$ and when $x=1$ you have $u=0$.